# submit a form using javascript to redirect

Tags: google-apps-script

Until last week i could use the following html to redirect a user to another page but since this monday this code stop working in gas (still works in caja-playground so caja must not be the source of the problem).

Any ideas why that happened?

```
<html>
 <body>
   <form action="www.url.com" id='redirect' method='get'>
     <input type='hidden' name='type' value='hi'>
     <script>
       document.getElementById('redirect').submit();
     </script>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they've removed this feature purposely due to security concerns. I didn't liked it either, take a look at [the issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1995) I opened (that is already closed).

Comment: they should at least provide a way to redirect to another page in the same script. Yes you can serve another html file after the form submission but you are stuck with the link of the form submission.
E.g.
i submit a form with do get and i get a link like 
    `...?type=formSubmit&id=123 `
normally after the submittion you would redirect to
    `...?type=start`
but now the only thing you can do is stay at
    `...?type=formSubmit&id=123`
and return the html file of the page you would redirect normally to breaking the back button amongst other things

Answer (score 0):

Now if you create a link with HtmlService:

```
<a href="?data=12">Redierect to my app"</a>
```

GAS will prepend your scripts url to the href.

so for example a form submit is a two click process.

```
<script>
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(reloadDash)
.withFailureHandler(foundError)
.processWelcomeForm(this.parentNode)
  });


function reloadDash(e){
$('#btnSubmit').hide();
$('#redirectURL').show();
}

 function foundError(e){
  alert("Oops somthing broke: " + e);
  }

</script>

<html>
<form id="myForm">
<button id="btnSubmit" class="blue">Save Info</button>
<a  href="?setup=1" id="redirectURL" style="display:none">
<button id="btnSubmit" class="blue">Saved..continue on with this app</button>
</a>
</form>
```